# Video.js Conflict with Slidebars.js Or Mmenu.js

Tags: video.js, mmenu

Im doing a video site and required to have video.js on the site. But i also need a push menu so i used first mmenu. The problem is my video player stops when the js of mmenu is loaded. Same happens when i tried slidebars.js. When i remove them the player works fine.

here are some errors i got but i also see this even the video is working fine.

```
   Video Error 
_V_.Event
altKey: undefined
attrChange: undefined
attrName: undefined
bubbles: false
button: undefined
cancelable: false
charCode: undefined
clientX: undefined
clientY: undefined
ctrlKey: undefined
currentTarget: video#example_video_1_html5_api.vjs-tech
data: undefined
detail: undefined
eventPhase: 2
fromElement: undefined
handler: undefined
isDefaultPrevented: function returnFalse(){return false}
isPropagationStopped: function returnTrue(){return true}
keyCode: undefined
metaKey: undefined
newValue: undefined
offsetX: undefined
offsetY: undefined
originalEvent: Event
pageX: undefined
pageY: undefined
prevValue: undefined
relatedNode: undefined
relatedTarget: undefined
result: undefined
screenX: undefined
screenY: undefined
shiftKey: undefined
srcElement: video#example_video_1_html5_api.vjs-tech
target: div#example_video_1.video-js.vjs-default-skin.vjs-paused
timeStamp: 1402109749287
toElement: undefined
type: "error"
vdata1402109746116: true
view: undefined
wheelDelta: undefined
which: undefined
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: What version of Video.js? From the `_V_` I'm assuming v3, in which case I'd suggest upgrading to 4 and see if you can still reproduce.

Comment: Same result also im seeing this classes when my video stops, vjs-paused vjs-user-inactive i found out that mmenu.js is not the problem instead the script to make it work this one 
`<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$('#side-menu').mmenu();
 $('.toggle-menu').on('click',function(){
      $('.mm-page').toggleClass('lock');
});
      });
 
</script> ` here is my test page [link]http://test.flippish.com/?p=32[/link]